# Does $ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{H_{k-1}}{k(k+n)}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{H_k}{k} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

I have been trying to do Problem 1.3.2 from the fantastic Almost Impossible Integrals book using different solution techniques.  I tried using a Cauchy product expansion and I managed to simplify it somewhat. Provided I have not made a mistake to this point I have the result.
$$
J_n = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{2H_{k-1}}{k(k+n)}
$$

The answer given in the book is:
$$
J_n = \frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{H_k}{k}
$$

If my answer is correct then we have the result:
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{H_{k-1}}{k(k+n)}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{H_k}{k}
$$

Is this correct if so how can you prove it?  I am positively stumped here.  I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: You may look at proof of lemma 1.1 [here](http://files.ele-math.com/articles/jca-09-15.pdf) .. :)

Comment: Summation by parts and you are done.